# Excel VBA Static Timestamp in Worksheet_Change event

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on creating a log that will automatically populate a timestamp into Cell D, when data is initially entered into Cell C. Unfortunately I have hit a wall.

- When I enter data in Cell C, I am able to get the timestamp in Cell D, but if I make any changes to Cell C, the timestamp updates again.
- I need to make it function so that the timestamp will ONLY change in Cell D if Cell C is blank.
- If data already has been entered into Cell C, and a timestamp already has been loaded to Cell D, and I need to modify what's in cell C, I don't want the timestamp Cell D to change.

Hope that makes sense. VBA code is as follows:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim rChange As Range

    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Set rChange = Intersect(Target, Range("C:C"))
    If Not rChange Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        For Each rCell In rChange
            If rCell > "" Then
                With rCell.Offset(0, 1)
                    .Value = Now
                    .NumberFormat = "hh:mm:ss AM/PM mm/dd/yyyy"
                End With
            Else
                rCell.Offset(0, 1).ClearContents
            End If
        Next
    End If

ExitHandler:
    Set rCell = Nothing
    Set rChange = Nothing
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume ExitHandler
End Sub
```

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Your current code shows one condition where you remove the timestamp from column D (although the logic behind when thisd happens appears wrong). Please elaborate on what you want to happen under each condition that could arise; 1. No timestamp in column D and value in column C. 2. Timestamp in column D and no value in column C. 3. No value in columns D or C. 4. Values in both columns C & D.

Comment: Hi Jeeped, let me try and explain what I am trying to do a little better. I am creating a logging template to run outage calls. Column C is titled Even Details, and initially will be blank. When ever something notable occurs during the outage, a team member will enter this into Column C. When someone enters data into a blank cell in Column C, I want a time stamp to appear in Column D. If someone goes to make a correction to an entry in Column C, I do NOT want the timestamp in Column D to update. If they delete all data in Column C, then I want the time stamp to disappear.

Comment: So to answer your above conditions:
1. Should not occur. If there is data in C, then D should populate a timestamp.
2.Should not occur. Timestamp only appears when data entered into C.
3. Both columns should be blank
4. Data will show in Column C, and a timestamp will appear in column D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following puts a timestamp into column D if there isn't one there when a value is typed into column C. If the value in column C is cleared, any existing timestamp in column D is also cleared. If an edit is made to an entry in column C, then no change is made to the existing timestamp.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Columns("C"), Target.Parent.UsedRange) Is Nothing Then
        On Error GoTo Safe_Exit
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Dim rng As Range
        For Each rng In Intersect(Target, Columns("C"), Target.Parent.UsedRange)
            If CBool(Len(rng.Value2)) And Not CBool(Len(rng.Offset(0, 1).Value2)) Then
                rng.Offset(0, 1) = Now
            ElseIf Not CBool(Len(rng.Value2)) And CBool(Len(rng.Offset(0, 1).Value2)) Then
                rng.Offset(0, 1) = vbNullString
            End If
        Next rng
    End If
Safe_Exit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

This routine will handle multiple cells as Target; typically when several rows of data is pasted into column C. It further restricts Intersection to the worksheet's UsedRange property so that processing is minimized when actions like row deletion are performed.

Comment: Thank you so much for the prompt response Jeeped! Forgive my ignorance, but I don't have much experience with VBA, so I'm not sure where I should stick this addition.

Comment: It replaces the one you quoted in your question.

Comment: Hmm, when I replace it and try to run it, I get a Compile Error: Sub or Function not defined. It then highlights the first isblank

Comment: Yeah, that should have been IsEmpty, not IsBlank. I've changed the logic above.

Comment: Jeeped, you are a beast. Thank you so much for your assistance! I've inserted the new code, and it is working as expected! I am very new to VBA, and was wondering if you could point me to a good place to learn the basics. Thanks again, you're the best!

Answer (score 3):

Seems simple enough.  Am I missing something?  Just check to ensure the cell is blank before you update it.

```
With rCell.Offset(0, 1)
    If .Value <> "" Then
        .Value = Now
        .NumberFormat = "hh:mm:ss AM/PM mm/dd/yyyy"
    End If
End With
```

Comment: Hi John, When entered your suggestion, the time stamp failed to appear altogether.