# Type Mismatch error with cell selection

Tags: excel, vba

I created this basic worksheet_change function which monitors column B. If a cell in column B gets deleted, it updates the delete in column C as well. The only issue is that since this is a change event, when more then 2 cells are altered at once, it throws a type mismatch error. This is because its comparing the Target.Address(s) to "" which is a type mismatch. How can I fix this to only run if only a single cell is select and not crash on a multiple cell select?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)


Dim KeyCells As Range
Set KeyCells = Range("B2:B51")

    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
        If Range(Target.Address).Value = "" Then
            Range("C" & Target.Row).Clear
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Before `Dim KeyCells as Range`, add `If Target.Count > 1 then Exit Sub`.

Comment: Ahh! So you can use the .Count function on a range. That is so convenient. Thank you for teaching me that! Please place your comment in a form of an answer so I can reward you.

Comment: also, there is no need to use `Range(Target.Address)` , since the `Target` is already a Range, simply use `Target`. in a whole line `If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Target)) Is Nothing Then`

Comment: Again, another good catch! Thank you for the tip Shai. I'll have to be more weary about that next time.

Comment: See [Excel VBA Static Timestamp in Worksheet_Change event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42729529/excel-vba-static-timestamp-in-worksheet-change-event/42766361#42766361) for tips on handing situations where Target is more than a single cell.

Comment: You also are not disabling events before clearing the value in column C.

Comment: @Jeeped Are you saying with Application.EnableEvents = False & Application.EnableEvents = True?

Comment: Yes. Failure to use `Application.EnableEvents = False` means that the routine will try to run on top of itself when you clear (aka change) the value in column C. `Application.EnableEvents = True` belongs in error control and is run as the event macro exits, regardless of whether it was turned off at any earier point.

Comment: @Jeeped what exactly happens if you fail to Re-Enable events after a sub ends? Will they remain off untill called to be true again? If this is the case, how does one implement turning it back to true in this line: `If Target.Count > 1 then Exit Sub`?

Comment: @Brad - See my answer, I edited it to turn events back on.

Comment: You can manually turn events back on by pastying `Application.EnableEvents = True` into the VBE's Immediate window and hitting Enter. To avoid turning events off don't call `Application.EnableEvents = False` until you know you are going to write something to the worksheet and always use `Application.EnableEvents = True` before exiting the event sub, regardless of whether you have turned them off or not. An error handler is the best place for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To simply check if the `Target` Range changed is more than one cell, you can simply count the cells in the range.

As mentioned in the comment, right after you declare the sub, you can add:

`If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub`.

Alternatively, of course you could do, `If Target.Count = 1 Then ...`

Edit: Per your question above, you can do this to make sure events are on:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Count > 1 Then
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
End If

' Code here that will run, if the Target is just one cell

End Sub
```