# excel vba worksheet change compile error

Tags: vba, excel

I am attempting a worksheet change, anytime there is a value in sheet4.cells("b2"), then it references sheet2, and returns the information from the matched row into the text boxes. I was running this as a test to get it right, once I do there will be 100+ text and check boxes. When a value is input into "B2" I get a compile error, Method or data member not found, highlighting the Private Sub Worksheet_Change(byVal target as Range). Code Below

```
Dim i As Variant, id As Long, j As Variant, flag As Boolean

Private Sub clearform()

For j = 1 To 2
    Sheet4.Controls("textbox" & j).Value = ""
Next j

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Range("b2").Value <> "" Then

    If IsNumeric(Sheet4.Cells("b2")) Then
        i = 0
        id = Sheet4.Cells("b2").Value

        Do While Sheet2.Cells(i + 1, 1).Value <> ""

            If Sheet2.Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = id Then
               For j = 1 To 2
                  Sheet2.Cells(i + 1, j).Value = Sheet4.Controls("textbox" & j).Value

               Next j

           End If

            i = i + 1

        Loop

    Else
        clearform
    End If

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: 1. Tighten what actually causes processing to occur with INtersect. 2. Turn off events before writing to teh worksheet so you do not run Worksheet_Change on top of itself. 3. Handle situations where Target may represent more than a single cell.

Comment: I am very new to vba, could you help me out with the code? what do you mean handle situations where target may represent more than a single cell?

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42729529/excel-vba-static-timestamp-in-worksheet-change-event/42766361#42766361). It puts all three of the things I mentioned into play.

Comment: to Jeeped's solution: in point 2. If you don't want to turn events off and on, you can use `If Not (Target.Cells(i, j) Is Nothing)...` to check if the specific cell was changed